# Use keys from JSON object to parse data and display as a list

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have an API that returns a JSON object with keys:
http://acnhapi.com/v1/bugs

Since it's not an array, I'd like to understand how to traverse it. I am trying to get a list of the bug names "common butterfly" and "yellow butterfly" etc. by using their keys `common_butterfly` and `yellow_butterfly` etc.

I want to display the value of `common_butterfly.name.name-USen`, but for each bug. So my list view should ultimately be displayed as:

- common butterfly
- yellow butterfly
- tiger butterfly
- etc.

(Alphabetical would be a bonus)

**data**

```
import SwiftUI

struct Bugs: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
}

class FetchBugs: ObservableObject {
  @Published var bugs = [Bugs]()
     
    init() {
        let url = URL(string: "http://acnhapi.com/v1/bugs")!
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let bugsData = data {
                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Bugs].self, from: bugsData)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.bugs = decodedData
                    }
                } else {
                    print("No data")
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

**list**

```
import SwiftUI

struct BugList: View {
    @ObservedObject var fetch = FetchBugs()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(fetch.bugs) { bug in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(bug.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct BugList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        BugList()
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your issue here, is it about json decoding or how to access the `bugs` array/dictionary  or is it about the SwiftUI part somehow?

Comment: Accessing `X.name.name-USen` where X is the key in the JSON object. Right now the VStack in my List is not accessing the correct field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this solution you can decode all your localised names:

```
struct Bug: Decodable, Identifiable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case name }
    
    let id = UUID()
    var localizedNames: [String: String] = [:]
    
    var nameUSen: String {
        localizedNames["name-USen"] ?? "error"
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let names = try container.decode([String: String].self, forKey: .name)
        for (key, value) in names {
            localizedNames[key] = value
        }
    }
}
```

Use `.sorted { $0.nameUSen < $1.nameUSen }` to *sort* your data:

```
class FetchBugs: ObservableObject {
    @Published var bugs = [Bug]()

    init() {
        let url = URL(string: "http://acnhapi.com/v1/bugs")!
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            do {
                if let bugsData = data {
                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: Bug].self, from: bugsData)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.bugs = Array(decodedData.values).sorted { $0.nameUSen < $1.nameUSen }
                    }
                } else {
                    print("No data")
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

And display the `USen` name:

```
struct BugList: View {
    @ObservedObject var fetch = FetchBugs()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(fetch.bugs) { bug in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(bug.nameUSen)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you'd ever want to access any other name you can use:

```
bug.localizedNames["name-EUde"]!
```

Comment: This logic makes sense but I'm unable to render a list with values using this method. Is the array empty on your end?

Comment: @OP I tested it in Xcode 11.5 / Swift 5.2.4 / iOS 13.5 (in previews as well). Did you try to run my code alone?

Comment: Tested purely your code on xcode 11.4 via previews. Will update and try again.

Comment: Still an empty list, no data, running the same specs as you :(

I have your first two code blocks in a Data.swift and the last code block in BugList.swift (with a previews struct). Am I missing anything else?

Comment: @OP Note that in the View I'm using `Text(bug.nameUSen)` instead of `Text(bug.name)`.

Comment: Saw that you were constructing nameUSen  What's odd is changing the resource call to https fixed it... guess I didn't have unsecured configured in Info.plist? Not even sure how to do that, but another question for another day. New to xcode... Thanks for your help!

Comment: @OP Oh, apologies... I used a test project created a long time ago and now I see I changed the Info.plist earlier.

Comment: Sorry - another quick Q: Am I reading this correctly - `bugs` is now a list of the bug names in asc order and no longer has access to the other values (price, etc.) in the same obj?

Comment: I didn't add them in this demo, however, you can add them in `init(from decoder: Decoder)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a playground that illustrates getting all bug's names in alphabetical order:

```
struct Bug: Decodable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name: Name

    struct Name: Decodable {
        let nameUSen: String

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case nameUSen = "name-USen"
        }
    }
}

do {
    let butterflies = try Data(contentsOf: URL(string: "http://acnhapi.com/v1/bugs")!)
    let allBugs = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: Bug].self, from: butterflies)

    let bugs = Array(allBugs.values.sorted { $0.name.nameUSen < $1.name.nameUSen })
    bugs.forEach { print($0.name.nameUSen) }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to call `name` as `bug.name` in the BugList view

Comment: You'd have to use `bug.name.nameUSen`, as in my example.